# Why is JsonObject empty despite the string provided in its constructor being correct?

Tags: java, json

So, I am trying to make a JsonObject using org.json library, from a string.
This is the code I am using:

```java
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

while (fScanner.hasNextLine()) {
       line.append(fScanner.nextLine());
}

System.out.println(line);

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(line);

System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

But the output I am getting is showing, empty JsonObject but correct string. It looks like this:

```text
{"username": "Sam","name": "Sam Anderson","points": "150"}
{}
```

Comment: `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(line.toString());` ??

Comment: Ah yes! Overlooked that, Thank you!